# Querying views and functions

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

How to query non-model views or table returning functions with Ecto? In my case the function (taking one argument) returns the same columns as one of my models and would just need to be read only.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. Do you want to run a custom SQL command? If so, check `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(...)`.

Comment: If I have a comment model for blog posts this function would return the comments for a specific post with some different data and special ordering. 

The query in SQL would look like `select * from special_comments(1)` 

Then I want to use the result to render the comments. Using `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(...)` how would I get it into Comment records?

Comment: I see. I sent an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell Ecto to load data from any view or table as follows:

```
from c in "special_comments(1)"
```

If you want to load that into a particular module, you can do:

```
from c in {"special_comments(1)", MyApp.Comment}
```

And you should be good to go!

Comment: While this doesn't work for functions it does do so for views and I think this should also be mentioned in the docs. 

Managed to convert the result of `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(...)` manually going over the returned rows in the meantime.

Comment: Ah, it won't work for functions because we wrap what you give in quotes.